# Multiple instances of same Vulkan subpass

Tags: vulkan

I have been reading through many online tutorials on creating a Vulkan renderer, however, the idea of subpasses is still very unclear to me.

Say I have the following scenario: I need to do a first subpass for setup (fill a depth buffer for testing etc) then have a subpass for every light in the scene (the number of which could change at any time). Because each lighting subpass is exactly the same, would it be possible to declare 2 subpasses and have multiple instances of the same subpass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "pass" here does not mean "full-screen pass" or something like that. Subpasses only matter in terms of what you're rendering to (and reading from previous subpass renderings as input attachments). Where your data comes from (descriptors/push constants), what vertex data they get, what shaders they use, none of that matters to the subpass. The only things the subpass controls are render targets.

So unless different lights are rendering to different images, then there's no reason to give each light a subpass. You simply issue the rendering commands for all of your lights within the same subpass.

Comment: What if I want each light to be in its own thread? I would want the drawing commands to be sent after each thread completes so that rendering doesn't wait on all the lights to be finished - sorry if this question is basic

Comment: @RWilco8: In their own CPU thread? That doesn't make sense; commands are not executed in multiple CPU threads. You put them into CBs in multiple CPU threads. And there's already a way to handle that: secondary command buffers. Also, if you're doing deferred rendering, there's no reason to do this, since the number of commands per light is very small.

Comment: Ah yes, I would like to use forward rendering where the scene is rendered as a series of lights that additive blend into the result. By doing this I hope to make it highly parallel where each light can start its command building and submit as soon as its done using a threadpool.

Comment: @RWilco8: That's a terrible idea. The cost of `vkQueueSubmit` is *enormous*. That's why submit calls take a large array-of-arrays of command buffers: because you should throw as much work into a single submit call as possible. GPU/CPU parallelism should be obtained by you preparing commands for frame 2 while the GPU is rendering frame 1. Not by the GPU executing some commands for frame 2 while you're generating more.

Comment: AFAICT, the prototypical use-case for subpasses is deferred rendering.

Comment: @PabloH: Um, sure, that is the typical thinking when it comes to subpasses. But that's hardly the totality of their use cases. Indeed, traditional forward rendering can in theory be accelerated by the use of subpasses. Keeping the depth buffer on-chip, without any backing memory, is a useful optimization, one that benefits forward rendering as much as deferred.